# Calculate expected value from joint probability density function of two random variables

Tags: probability

A joint probability density function of two random variables $Y_1$
and $Y_2$ is given by
$$f\left(y_{1}, y_{2}\right)= \begin{cases}k y_{1} y_{2}, & 0 \leq y_{1} \leq 1 \text { y } 0 \leq y_{2} \leq 1 \\ 0, & \text { otherwise }\end{cases}$$

a) Find the value of the constant
$k$, for which f is the joint probability density function.

b) Find $E[Y_1-Y2]$

I calculated $k$ which is 4, my problem is part b) because
\begin{align}E[Y_1-Y_2]=&E[Y_1]-E[Y_2]\\
=&\int^1_0y_1f_{y_1}(y_1)dy_1-\int^1_0y_2f_{y_2}(y_2)dy_2\\
=&\int^1_0y_12y_1dy_1-\int^1_0y_22y_2dy_2\\
=&\int^1_02y_1^2dy_1-\int^1_02y_2^2dy_2= \frac{2}{3}- \frac{2}{3}=0
\end{align}

My result is correct? thanks

Comment: I think so. It makes intuitive sense. Since $f(y_1,y_2)=f(y_1)f(y_2)$ Identical and  independent distributions, they would have the same expectation, hence the difference is 0.